# Oracle Db Group By Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I want to group by 2 columns my first table is:

**Users**

```
ID Name Surname
1  joe   New
2  Ala   Bla
3  Cat   Kra
4  Zoo   Fles
5  Kat   Glo
```

**Work:**

```
ID BOSSID1 BOSSID2
1  1       2
2  2       3
3  2       1
4  2       5
5  3       5
```

And I want to see all Bosses in table "Work".

for example:

```
1 joe   New
2 Ala   Bla
3 Cat   Kra
5 Kat   Glo
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first table be named bosses?

Comment: Show us your attempt

Comment: Please show us what your query looks like so far. [Spoiler Alert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM USERS u INNER JOIN WORK w 
ON (u.id = w.bossid1 OR u.id = w.bossid2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, concat(name, ' ', surname) from
(
    select id, name, surname from users 
    where id in 
    (
      select distinct bossid1 from work

    ) OR id in 
    (
      select distinct bossid2 from work
    )
)
```

Comment: That `CONCAT()` won't work - `CONCAT()` takes only two strings; you need to nest it to concatenate more than two.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `union` and then join with `users` table

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', U.Name, U.Surname)
FROM Users U
JOIN
(SELECT BOSSID1 as BossID
FROM WORK
UNION
SELECT BOSSID2 as BossID
FROM WORK
) T
on U.ID = T.BossID
```